# Calling object as function

Tags: javascript

I have a class defined like:

```
function S(items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.item = function(pos) {
        return this.items[pos];
    }
}
```

To retrieve the items, I normally do,

```
var s = new S([10, 20, 30]);
console.log(s.item(0));
console.log(s.item(1));
```

I want to change the way I access the items to be like:

```
var s = new S([10, 20, 30]);
console.log(s(0));
console.log(s(1));
```

Comment: Would using square brackets be OK instead? You can assign the properties to your object as `this[index] = items[index]`, then access them later using `console.log(s[0])`

Comment: Why? This seems like a confusing pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only *call* functions. The most close way to do what you are trying to accomplish is to make your function `S` return another function that receives the position as a parameter and returns the item in that position. And this way you'd need to stop using the `new` keyword.

```
function S(items) {
    return function(pos) {
        return items[pos]
    }
} 

var s = S([10, 20, 30])
console.log(s(0))
console.log(s(1))
```

Anyway, I can't see any good reason of why you would like to do that. If you are trying to freeze an array so it can't be modified, then I think using [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) would be a better choice.

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/84wVU/

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

But you can come close.

```
function S(items) {
    var l = items.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) this[i] = items[i];
}

var s = new S([10,20,30]);
console.log(s[0]); // note square brackets
```

Only functions can be called with `()`.

Comment: While technically true nothing stops you inheriting from a function by overriding your prototype and messing with the core way the language works(your object is a function and an object), provided of course you're willing to deal with edge case behaviours when stuff goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can indeed loop through the items and take each item in the array and attach it to the class as this[index] = items[index]. Another option is to extend the Array prototype to attach your current functions to it:

```
Array.prototype.item = function(pos){
   return this[pos];
}
```

Now you can call the item function on arrays like so :

```
[1,2,3,4].item(1) // will return 2
[1,2,3,4].item(2) // will return 3
```

and so on..